# buddypress on ONE site in multisite

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to de-bloat my wordpress site: https://trekfederation.com
I have all sorts of plugins that have nothing to do with the landing pages loading.  Some 94 js and css files.

I was recommended to run multisite, since I could setup plugins on each site, and not worry about the propogation across.  This will leave my landing site, store, learning center, and other  plugins on other sites.

Is there a way to choose when buddypress works? ie, can we set it up so buddypress works on site 2, 4, 6, but not 1, 3, and 5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to activate BuddyPress on one site of a multisite network. Check out the BP codex: https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/installation-in-wordpress-multisite/

Activating BP on more than one subsite can create some unexpected behavior.